# How to update HTML Header and specified Divs with new code in JAVA

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have few HTMLS where I want to find particular divs and update them with new Lines of Code.

Currently, I am using Jsoup as HTML parser in my JAVA backend but somehow it is not updating required content INSTEAD, removing Scripts and other sections from existing HTMLs.

Here is the code I am using.

```
File file = new File("C:/2015/05 May/sample.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(file, "UTF-8");
// clear the <head> element and add a new <script> element.
doc.head().appendElement("script")
        .attr("type", "text/javascript")
        .attr("src", "newScriptToAddInHeaderSection.js");


 for( Element element : doc.select("div.sampleDiv") )
 {
     element.remove();
     System.out.println("REMOVED..");
 }

//write the changed HTML to the same file.
BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(file)); 
bw.write(doc.html());
```

On execution of this code. It will add new JS file in Header Section. Then, It is removing "sampleDiv" but also other scripts and divs from my HTML.
I only need to update this "sampleDiv" with new Content.

Please help!!

Comment: I don't see any obvious problem with your code, other than that you say that you want to update the content of `sampleDiv`, but you are calling `element.remove();`, which removes it. Could you post some sample HTML which reproduces the problem, and perhaps also the expected output ?

Comment: Thing is.. IN the end of HTML, i have so many scripts code and div elements. On Executing of above code. It is somehow removing almost half of portion from my HTML. Update is fine.. that we can see but it should not affect other sections in HTML.

Comment: Can you give an example of your html? Just so the problem can be reproduced.

Answer (score 0):

> *It is removing "sampleDiv" but also other scripts and divs from my HTML.*

`element.remove();` will delete sampleDiv and all its children nodes from the HTML tree. This can explain why other scripts and divs get deleted also.

> *I only need to update this "sampleDiv" with new Content.*

Can you explicit what *this "sampleDiv"* is actually?